# Debian 11, MATE, crippled GUI yellow

Tags: debian, mate-desktop

Got dedicated server with preinstalled Debian 11 without GUI. 
Have ssh connection to it. 
Installed MATE.

```
apt install mate-desktop-environment lightdm
```

Made it login itself.  **Installed anydesk.** 
With `xrandr`, made screen 2160×1200. 
Enjoyed two days. 
Then some kind of magic happened. 
The GUI became yellowfish, and I see artifacts of closed windows. 
Reinstalled MATE, X11, and LightDM. 
Nothing helps. 
I cannot even understand what is the reason. 
What is happening (and why?) and how can I fix it?

This is the way it looks now: 
[image: screenshot]

[image: blue windows does not exist anymore, I can erase it moving yellow one]

Comment: Welcome to U&L Stack Exchange.  It would appear that you have accidentally created two accounts.  This will interfere with commenting, editing your own posts, and accepting an answer.  You should use the [contact form](/contact) and select “I need to merge user profiles” to have your accounts merged.  In order to merge them, you will need to provide links to the two accounts.  For your information, they are https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/538291/c4h7cl2o4p and https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/538293/c4h7cl2o4p.  You’ll then be able to [edit] your question without waiting for approval.

Answer (score 0):

My first assumption would be that the two most likely culprits behind the issue are the resolution and/or the network connection.

If you haven't already, try the following two steps independently of each other at first, and then together if neither of them help independently.

Step 1) If possible, try to connect to the server using an Ethernet Cable for a more stable connection.

Step 2) Go back to "xrandr" and reduce the resolution to "1024x768".

Let me know if those suggestions work or not.

If they don't, run the "dmesg" command on the server to view the kernel logs, and look through the date that the problem first occurred. This may provide some more in-depth diagnostic information.